# Flex 4.1 installed on a Mac: how do I target pre-version 10 flash players

Tags: version, flash, backwards-compatibility, apache-flex

I just installed (or copied) the Flex SDK 4.1 on my Mac to:

```
/Developer/SDKs/Flex/4/1/
```

For now I'll only be using a plain text-editor to use it. No fancy IDE.

However, it only seems to support flashplayers version 10 and 10.1. At least that's what it looks like from the folders:

```
./frameworks/libs/players/10.0/
./frameworks/libs/players/10.1/
```

I thought I was being smart and copied the version 9 swc from the SDK 3.4 to:

```
./frameworks/libs/players/9/
```

I also copied the flex-config.xml from the SDK 3.4 and renamed it.

When I tried to compile it with the SDK 4.1 by using the `-load-config` options however, it still complained about certain dependencies that were not found:

```
// Error: Type not found or no constant at compilation. Matrix3D.
Fout: Type niet gevonden of geen constante bij compilatie. Matrix3D.

/Developer/SDKs/Flex/4/1/frameworks/libs/flash-integration.swc(mx.utils:MatrixUtil)
```

So, I thought about copying flash-integration.swc also. But then I thought: before I go any further with tweaking the contents of the SDK 4.1 let's ask SO whether what I intend to do is even possible. Is it? Is it possible to target player 9 for instance with SDK 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex 4 and above requires Flash Player 10 or highr.  It makes use of some 10 specific features, such as the new text engine.  If you want to target 9 you'll have to use Flex 3.5 or lower.